# extjs, how to bind event in form actions?

Tags: javascript, extjs

like this.but handler do not work ,extjs version 3.2.0,please,thanks very much

```
form = new app.modules.form.TableFormView( {
                isCombined : true,
                entryName : "lite.manager.sc.ODG_CLUSTER",
                empiId : "",
                colCount : 1,
                actions : [{id:"toStandby",name:"test1",handler:function()  
                    console.log(111)
                    }},
                    {id:"refresh",name:"test2"}]
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but I think [the example given in the ExtJs documentation](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.0/docs/?class=Ext.util.Observable) might help you. Basically, your form object should extend Ext.util.Observable.